# Error with Rest Web service using spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm getting this exception while getting response from the server for all the web services

```
{"errorcode":"500","errormessage":org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream@18c792d1; line: 1, column: 2]}
```

The other web service, where I'm using mongoDB, is working fine.

Comment: you need to post your json

Comment: THis is the json data{"robotList":[{"id":1,"name":"HTS"},{"id":2,"name":"AIS"},{"id":3,"name":"POLY"},{"id":41,"name":"MFR"},{"id":91,"name":"3POD"},{"id":19,"name":"SIM2"}]} .All the web services were working fine before i did integration with mongo db.After integration only one service is working fine which is getting data from mongodb

Comment: {"robotList":[{"id":1,"name":"HTS"},{"id":2,"name":"AIS"},{"id":3,"name":"POLY"},{"id":41,"name":"MFR"},{"id":91,"name":"3POD"},{"id":19,"name":"SIM2"}]}  no its valid.even i checked it in jsonlint

Comment: @ScaryWombat it validates fine

Comment: @ankur-singhal Sorry C&P problem

Comment: @poonam The service you're accessing might be returning an xml response, not a json response.

Comment: @ankur-singhal k but it was working fine before i did mongodb integration and now suddenly stopped working

Comment: @poonam Before parsing the response, please try to alert/print that response, there might be some exception at server side, which is actually sending html content or maybe some xml. But print the response first.

Comment: the issue is resolved.                                              Thanks for all the help :) The issue was with port number but i don't know how i was getting 500 jsonparserexception where i was actually supposed to get 404 non found